# isalpha function in C using only & and <= operators

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

This is the problem:

Using only two operations in C ( & and <=), and up to a maximum of 5 operations, determine whether a character is alphabetical lowercase or uppercase. You may declare as many variables as you want, but you're limited to 5 operations of bitwise and (&) and the <= comparison.

example:

```
is_char('b') = 1
is_char('A') = 1
is_char(10) = 0
```

I can do it in 6 operations, but can't do it in 5.... Anyone have an idea?

Sorry!! Forgot to include that no one can use control flow statements :/

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Comment: It depends upon the character encoding (and UTF8 letters may be encoded in several bytes).

Comment: Is this assuming the letters have consecutive codes?

Comment: You could declare and fill a constant array, and use lookup with bitmasks inside it.

Comment: Please *show* the form with the 6 operations used.

Comment: I'm willing to bet it's something like `if (('A' <= c) & (c <= 'Z')) return true; else if (('a' <= c) & (c <= 'z')) return true; else return false;`.

Comment: Don't you just love homework assignments that teach bad habits.

Comment: @paddy, Because *nothing* anymore could possibly use EBCDIC ;)

Comment: These directions are really vague. @chris I was under the impression the C standard didn't guarantee order of the alphabet in the execution character set.

Comment: @oldrinb, I do believe you are correct. I reference EBCDIC because it's one where `for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; ++c) printf("%c", c);` won't do exactly what you'd expect.

Comment: I'm shocked by the number of people doing his homework, and the people that come after him. This can be done in 4 `<=` without a single `&` for your class if not following Bananeweizen's example.

Comment: @n00b post you current answer. It will lead to clarification and better help.

Comment: @James I just realized I was also using the >= operator :/ so I don't have a solution anymore. But if it helps it relied on using the & operator on single bits to check if they were greater or less than specified values ( 122, 97, 90, 65) since those are where the uppercase and lowercase ascii values are.

Comment: @n00b: `>=` is exactly equivalent to `<=` with the operands flipped...

Comment: This is stupid even for an assignment.  It might be interesting for learning logic expressions, but it would never be good code for handling text anymore.  It is practically certain in the future that you will be using unicode and not ascii.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how to do it with five operations and no control-flow statements. We avoid a second range test by dropping the 0x20 bit (mapping the `a-z` range onto the `A-Z` range):

```
int is_char(unsigned char c) {
    return ((c & ~0x20) <= 'Z') & ('A' <= (c & ~0x20))
}
```

Note that you can code `~0x20` as `0xdf` if you don't want `~` accidentally considered an operator.

Modifying `c` cuts this down to four ops, though the optimizer should see the redundancy:

```
int is_char(unsigned char c) {
    c &= ~0x20;
    return ('A' <= c) & (c <= 'Z');
}
```

Comment: Very nice! Masking the case off and then testing was holding me back from reducing the number of ops.

Answer (score 1):

Gabe you are forgetting that in C a char is represented as an int in the ASCII table. So this can be done in two operations. (I am thinking the OP didn't fully elaborate on the question however)

```
if (c <= 'A' - 1)
    return 0;
if ('z' + 1 <= c)
    return 0;
return 1;
```

Comment: What about the following characters between 'Z' and 'z': `5b  [    5c  \    5d  ]    5e  ^    5f  _ 60  `

Comment: new user tip: feel free to elaborate with your answers, especially when person who asked it you consider a newbie with subject, he/she will probably appreciate more explanation about ascii table, and how it works, with some link maybe..

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use `&` operator? If not, you can do it with 4 `<=` operations:

```
if (c <= 'A' - 1)
    return 0;
if (c <= 'Z')
    return 1;
if (c <= 'a' - 1)
    return 0;
if (c <= 'z')
    return 1;
return 0;
```

Note: this assumes ASCII, and the use of `'A' - 1` is just for illustration -- converting it to a constant is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: you can't use control flow statements like if :/ forgot to add that sorry